# SQlite3 problem with floating point for arm-linux

Tags: sqlite, floating-point, arm, type-conversion

I am trying to use sqlite-3.7.2 cross compiling it in two machines, an *arm-linux* and a *xscale* system, I have cross compile it using ./configure for both systems in a very normal way, indicating of course the host to compile.

The thing is that I have some REAL values on the database. I get the correct values for *xscale* system, but on the *arm7* I get an incorrect value for those that have decimal part, I mean;

If I have in my database table:
**REAL 2.00**
**REAL 2.02**

When I SELECT these values I get:
**2.00**
**-4310086189061.12**

For *xscale* is working fine, so I suppose that is a sqlite compilation issue for arm.

I have done a research and I didn't find so much, just this:
http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg40528.html
Where is suggested to use the -DSQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT=1 flag on compile time, but I can't find it on the code and doesn't work just adding it to the configure or Makefie.am files.

I will really appreciate if someone has any solution or information about this issue, because I am completely stuck

Thank you so much

JC

EDIT:
Solution that is working for me, before to cross compile sqlite3, define the variable CFLAGS on the environment:

$ **CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT=1 -DSQLITE_DEBUG=1"**
$ **export CFLAGS**

Comment: OK, I have found this variable on sqlite3.c in a #undef declaration, I don't know what I did wrong on my search on the code. I am going to compile sqlite3 again with this variable activated and hopefully will work.

Comment: I still have the same issue, any idea?

Comment: For those that could have my same problem, I've finally solved it. On the code is explained for the flag SQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT what is the issue. To solve it, is necessary to define on CFLAGS environment this flag (-DSQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT=1) and the flag -DSQLITE_DEBUG=1, this last flag assure to get the correct value. So, $ CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT=1 -DSQLITE_DEBUG=1" and $ export CFLAGS

Answer (score 1):

From the comment by the OP:

> For those that could have my same problem, I've finally solved it. On the code is explained for the flag `SQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT` what is the issue.
>
> To solve it, is necessary to define on CFLAGS environment this flag `(-DSQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT=1)` and the flag `-DSQLITE_DEBUG=1`, this last flag assure to get the correct value. So,

$ CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_MIXED_ENDIAN_64BIT_FLOAT=1 -DSQLITE_DEBUG=1"

and

$ export CFLAGS